# Why are my variables not being recognized by the scanner and fillRect?

Tags: java

I'm working on a task which involves drawing things at certain places on a 500px*500px JFrame using x/y coordinates. I can get the program to draw a location however it is completely disregarding the information it receives from the input file through the scanner and just draws the rectangle in the top left corner. Changing the values in towers.txt does nothing for some reason. What is wrong with my code?

First file...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File towers = new File("towers.txt");
        File readings = new File("readings.txt");
        Scanner towers1 = new Scanner("towers");
        Scanner readings1 = new Scanner("readings");
        ArrayList<Integer> towerPos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> readingPos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(towers1.hasNextDouble()) {
            towerPos.add((int)towers1.nextDouble());
        }

        while(readings1.hasNextDouble()) {
            readingPos.add((int)readings1.nextDouble());
        }


        JFrame f = new JFrame("Cellphone Coverage");
        f.setVisible(true);     
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(
            JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new CoveRage(towerPos, readingPos));

    }
}
```

Second file...

```
public class CoveRage 
extends JComponent {

    private ArrayList<Integer> readingPos;
    private ArrayList<Integer> towerPos;
    int xAxis;
    int yAxis;

    public CoveRage(ArrayList<Integer> towerPos, ArrayList<Integer> readingPos) {
         this.towerPos = towerPos;
         this.readingPos = readingPos;
        }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        for (int j = 0; j < towerPos.size(); j += 2) {
            int xAxis = towerPos.get(j) / 10;
            int yAxis = towerPos.get(j + 1) / 10;
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.fillRect(xAxis, yAxis, 5, 5);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized the `Scanner` with the actual `File`.  Try this code instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File towers = new File("towers.txt");
    File readings = new File("readings.txt");
    Scanner towers1 = new Scanner(towers);      // remember to initialize
    Scanner readings1 = new Scanner(readings);  // the Scanner with the file
    ArrayList<Integer> towerPos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> readingPos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(towers1.hasNextDouble()) {
        towerPos.add((int)towers1.nextDouble());
    }

    while(readings1.hasNextDouble()) {
        readingPos.add((int)readings1.nextDouble());
    }

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Cellphone Coverage");
    f.setVisible(true);     
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new CoveRage(towerPos, readingPos));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I changed that on purpose because I was getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: towers.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)" and I am now getting it again after changing my code back. The file is in the right directory I believe which is weird.

Comment: I added this in after I declared the file location "System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());" and it printed out the location of where the file is.

Comment: @pabloescobrah You need to put the full location of the file.  If your code be running as a Java console application (what I suspect), then you could try something like `new File("C:\Users\pablo\towers.txt")`, assuming the file `"towers.txt"` were located in that place on your C: drive.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you using a package? The file has to be in the main directory of your application, outside of any package to be recognized correctly just by "towers.txt".

Comment: @Aron_dc I'm using the Eclipse IDE and it says my .java files are in a default package. I put the towers.txt in the same folder as the .java files and also in the folder before that one.

Comment: Just right click the file name and get the full path of the file.  Then use this when you call the constructor `new File(...)`.  I believe this is the easiest way to get your code working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it gives me this error when I use the full path "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: @pabloescobrah Thats the problem. Putting the file in the same folder like the "java" files will put it in the src folder. Drag and drop it onto your project, this should put it in the base directory and it should be accessible from your program then by "towers.txt". (just tested a similar setup locally at my machine and it works)

Comment: OK.  You have two options.  Either you can use _forward_ slashes, e.g. `"C:/Users/pablo/towers.txt"`, or you can use _escaped_ backslashes, e.g. `"C:\\Users\\pablo\\towers.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I sorted out my problem!